# Passwordless login to a specific directory by SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I know how to login without password to remote host by SSH. But that way I can access to all folder to remote host. Is there any way to give access to only specific folders by SSH?

I used `ssh-keygen` to generate public-private key pairs and then added public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in remote server.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about things that should be handled with user level permissions, not via SSH . . .

Comment: all i want if i use ssh://user@host/~/abc/mydir to access user@host then i can access only mydir directory and its child, not abc.

Comment: As you tagged with `git`, I assume you want to implement some sort of access control on top of git via ssh. If that's the case, have a look at e.g. gitolite.

Comment: You could set user's home directory to be the directory you want to limit it to, but that's going to break any other ssh access they make . . .

Comment: I've just removed the git tag as it wasn't correctly tagged. Please add it back if you update your post with git-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You want sftponly.  It is a little involved to set up, but I have it running for two dozen sftp only clients.  It performs a chroot when the user connects and it prevents ssh access  -- thus the name.

https://www.allthingsdigital.nl/2013/05/12/setting-up-an-sftp-only-account-with-openssh/

Note that you can't allow the user to have write access in the dir they log into, but you can bind mount any other directories and give them r/w access to them.